# Como fazer 'increment' em variáveis

Tags: java, array, operadores

No código abaixo minha variável y pede para que o usuário insira valores até o y chegar em 10, faço o armazenamento na variável x e atualmente a ultima informação digitada é a armazenada(que mostra no fim do código) o que eu gostaria de saber é como fazer um "increment" na var x, armazenando a informação digitada em x1, x2, x3..até x10, como ocorre com o Y.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    public class SEP_06_exe2_p1{
        public static void main(String args[]){
             int x;
             int y = 1;
             do{         
                 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
                 System.out.print("Digite o " + y + "º valor: ");
                 x = input.nextInt();
                 y = ++y; //incrementa 1 no y 
             }while( y <= 10);
             System.out.print(x);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Esse incremente que estás a falar, chama-se preencher um array. Tu se tiveres o x como int nunca vais conseguir guardar os valores

Comment: Pelo que percebi estas a iniciar com esta linguagem, e sem querer distorcer o plano de estudo, gostaria antes de responder se podes utilizar `Arrays` para resolver esta cituação?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basicamente o que você precisa fazer é utilizar um *[array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure)* ([tutorial Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) e [documentação da classe](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)). Ele é uma variável que guarda vários valores (uma coleção de valores). Daí você acessa cada valor individual através do seu índice. Seria alguma coisa mais ou menos assim (não testei, nem sei se o que você fez está funcionando, coloquei para ilustrar o que você precisa usar):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class SEP_06_exe2_p1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[] x = new int[10];
        int y = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {         
            System.out.print("Digite o " + (y + 1) + "º valor: ");
            x[y] = input.nextInt();
            y++; //incrementa 1 no y <== estava errado veja nota abaixo
        } while (y < 10);
        y = 0;
        do {         
            System.out.println(x[y]);
            y++;
        } while (y < 10);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/zDoW6n). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ejuzndls-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/ReadNumbers.java).

O operador `++` gera efeito colateral, ou seja, ele modifica o estado da própria variável, então você não precisa atribuir o resultado para uma variável. `y++` é a mesma coisa que dizer `y += 1` que o mesmo que dizer `y = y + 1`. Tem como simplificar isto ainda mais , mas como você está começando e há controvérsias se essa simplificação é boa, não vou citá-la.

*Arrays* começam sempre do zero. Por isto mudei o valor inicial de `y` e a comparação do `while` para terminar antes de chegar no 10, ou seja ele vai de 0 à 9.

Você poderia usar um controle de fluxo `for` neste caso, simplifica um pouco. Mas dê um passo de cada vez.

Comment: Teria como eu chamaria para ver (testar) essas variáveis armazenadas em x para uma futura validação?
ex: System.out.printf(?????);

Comment: Você quer passar para outro método como na outra questão? Se for isto, certamente, é só passar o `x`. Claro que o método tem que estar esperando um argumento do tipo *array*. O que diretamente não é o caso do `print`. Mas aí talvez já seria outra pergunta.

Comment: Sim, p ser mais exato o q desejo é 'Fazer um prog que leia 10 valores e imprime ordenados', no outro prog eu li os valores e imprimi o maior, não usei array, devo usar array para entende-lo, neste caso estou tentando diminuir as linhas de código, invés de usar 10 vars pensei em usar como acima o do|while p armazenar as informações e passar para validação via array os valores. Posteriormente vou diminuir o tamanho da validação também, mas estou indo passo a passo por que quero ir entendendo certinho, se souber de algum site q tenha algumas explicações que possam me ajudar seria ótimo! Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar utilizar o código abaixo, que realizará um somatório(guardaX) dos valores de x como acontece com a variavel y:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    public class SEP_06_exe2_p1{
        public static void main(String args[]){
             int x;
             int guardaX = 0;
             int y = 1;
             do{         
                 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
                 System.out.print("Digite o " + y + "º valor: ");
                 x = input.nextInt();
                 guardaX = x + guardaX;
                 y = ++y; //incrementa 1 no y 
             }while( y <= 10);
             System.out.println(x);
             System.out.println(guardaX);
        }
   }
```

Comment: Acho que você não entendeu o que o AP está precisando.